React Native web webview : onNavigationStateChange is not getting called in web app (chrome)
Same library i have added in mobile application and its working fine for both android and ios as well.
The below response coming in mobile application with onNavigationStateChange event.
{"canGoBack": false, "canGoForward": false, "loading": true, "target": 21057, "title": "url", "url": "google.com"}
Please suggest for web application. (I am using react native web for web application
)
